# QPID - Spring CachingConnectionFactory - Reconnect

Tags: java, spring, qpid

Spring Configuration

```
 <bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0"
        value="amqp://guest:guest@localhost/test?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672'" />
</bean>

<bean id="cachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="1" />
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="myDestination" class="org.apache.qpid.client.AMQAnyDestination">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="ADDR:myqueue; {create: always}" />
</bean>

<bean id="myServiceBean" class="com.test.MyService" />

<bean id="myContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="exceptionListener" ref="cachingConnectionFactory" /> 
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myServiceBean" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="destination" ref="myDestination" />
    <property name="recoveryInterval" value="10000" />      
</bean>
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {        
    log.info("----On Message called :"+msg+", :"+msg.getClass().getName());         
    }
}
```

**When I restart QPID**

**Without reconnectOnException=true,I keep getting this exception ,but not reconneting**

```
3203 [myContainer-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory  - Creating cached JMS Session for mode 1: org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession_0_10@1d03a4e
3312 [myContainer-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory  - Creating cached JMS MessageConsumer for destination ['myqueue'/None; {
  'create': 'always'
}]: org.apache.qpid.client.BasicMessageConsumer_0_10@8a2023
99109 [myContainer-1] WARN org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination ''myqueue'/None; {
  'create': 'always'
}' - trying to recover. Cause: timed out waiting for session to become open (state=DETACHED)
org.apache.qpid.transport.SessionException: timed out waiting for session to become open (state=DETACHED)
    at org.apache.qpid.transport.Session.invoke(Session.java:630)
    at org.apache.qpid.transport.Session.invoke(Session.java:559)
    at org.apache.qpid.transport.SessionInvoker.executionSync(SessionInvoker.java:84)
    at org.apache.qpid.transport.Session.sync(Session.java:782)
    at org.apache.qpid.transport.Session.sync(Session.java:770)
    at org.apache.qpid.client.BasicMessageConsumer_0_10.getMessageFromQueue(BasicMessageConsumer_0_10.java:423)
    at org.apache.qpid.client.BasicMessageConsumer.receive(BasicMessageConsumer.java:407)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachedMessageConsumer.receive(CachedMessageConsumer.java:74)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:429)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:310)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1058)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:947)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
99109 [myContainer-1] INFO org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection

..

281125 [myContainer-3] INFO org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

**With reconnectOnException=true ,Its getting connected and disconnected**

```
    13015 [IoReceiver - localhost/127.0.0.1:5672] WARN org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory  - Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
javax.jms.JMSException: connection aborted
    at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_0_10.closed(AMQConnectionDelegate_0_10.java:303)
    at org.apache.qpid.transport.Connection.closed(Connection.java:568)
    at org.apache.qpid.transport.network.Assembler.closed(Assembler.java:110)
    at org.apache.qpid.transport.network.InputHandler.closed(InputHandler.java:202)
    at org.apache.qpid.transport.network.io.IoReceiver.run(IoReceiver.java:150)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.qpid.transport.ConnectionException: connection aborted
    at org.apache.qpid.transport.Connection.closed(Connection.java:541)
    ... 4 more
13031 [IoReceiver - localhost/127.0.0.1:5672] DEBUG org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory  - Closing shared JMS Connection: AMQConnection:
Host: localhost
Port: 5672
Virtual Host: test
Client ID: localhost
Active session count: 1
73031 [IoReceiver - localhost/127.0.0.1:5672] DEBUG org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory  - Could not close shared JMS Connection
org.apache.qpid.client.JMSAMQException: timed out waiting for session to become open (state=DETACHED)
    at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnection.stop(AMQConnection.java:824)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.closeConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.resetConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.resetConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.onException(SingleConnectionFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.ChainedExceptionListener.onException(ChainedExceptionListener.java:57)
    at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_0_10.closed(AMQConnectionDelegate_0_10.java:306)
    ...
    at org.apache.qpid.transport.network.io.IoReceiver.run(IoReceiver.java:150)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.qpid.AMQException: timed out waiting for session to become open (state=DETACHED) [error code 541: internal error]
    at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession_0_10.setCurrentException(AMQSession_0_10.java:1050)
    at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession_0_10.sync(AMQSession_0_10.java:1030)
    at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession_0_10.sendSuspendChannel(AMQSession_0_10.java:857)
    at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession.suspendChannel(AMQSession.java:3006)
    at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession.stop(AMQSession.java:2341)
    at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnection.stop(AMQConnection.java:820)
    ... 11 more
```

```
104875 [myContainer-1] INFO org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory  - Established shared JMS Connection: AMQConnection:
Host: localhost
Port: 5672
Virtual Host: test
Client ID: localhost
Active session count: 0
104875 [myContainer-1] INFO org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
104875 [myContainer-2] DEBUG org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory  - Creating cached JMS Session for mode 1: org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession_0_10@191e4c
104937 [IoReceiver - localhost/127.0.0.1:5672] WARN org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory  - Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
javax.jms.JMSException: 404
    at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnection.exceptionReceived(AMQConnection.java:1230)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.qpid.AMQException: ch=0 id=0 ExecutionException(errorCode=NOT_FOUND, commandId=0, description=Queue: myqueue not found) [error code 404: not found]
    at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession_0_10.setCurrentException(AMQSession_0_10.java:1050)
    ... 29 more
104937 [IoReceiver - localhost/127.0.0.1:5672] DEBUG org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory  - Closing shared JMS Connection: AMQConnection:
Host: localhost
Port: 5672
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried omitting the exceptionListener setting on the DMLC?  I don't recall ever needing to specify that, and it seems like your connection is being invalidated after connection recovery has been initiated.

Also, assuming you're not using JBoss 4, you might try using the DMLC's built-in caching mechanism (via the cacheLevel setting) instead of using a caching connection factory for your consumers; you may even get better performance, since DMLC can cache sessions and consumers as well as connections.